# Remove Arduino Launch Target in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, arduino

I'm not sure if this belongs here or in the Arduino community, but I am setting up the Eclipse IDE for Arduino environment, and after getting a launch target to work, I'm not sure how to remove the incorrect launch targets.  I now have a total of 4 launch targets, and I only want one.

How can I remove these unwanted launch targets?

Picture of the launch targets:
[image: Launch targets]

Thanks,
- Ben

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same issue.
In Eclipse, you will find a Tab called "Connections" where the Launch Targets are listed. Just right-click on one and delete it.

Comment: please add an Image for the same, It will be easier for finding the "connections" tab. It is just right to "Project Explorer Tab"  which normally in the Left side of the eclipse window.